# Unable to install plugin hostmanager in vagrant in windows 8.1

Tags: plugins, vagrant

Not able to install plugin its showing the below error...

C:\devbox>vagrant plugin install 'vagrant-hostmanager' 
The directory where plugins are installed (the Vagrant home directory)
has a space in it. On Windows, there is a bug in Ruby when compiling
plugins into directories with spaces. Please move your Vagrant home
directory to a path without spaces and try again.

Comment: hi, did you resolve the issue? I would expect you aren't the first nor will you be the last with this little problem. Let's close this issue and move on (you can accept my answer)

Answer (score 17):

Ruby (language used by Vagrant) has "issues" with directory names that contain spaces.

Vagrant will use an environment variable (supplied by windows) to tell it where your user directory is (so it can decide where to put your "home" directory). *But* you might have a space in your user name (I do) which causes a problem for ruby (which is doing the work to install the plugin).

The solution is to move your project to a project directory you choose that doesn't have any spaces in the directory name. Then, use an environment variable called `VAGRANT_HOME` and set it to a specified directory. The plugin installation procedure will check for the existence of this variable and use it if it exists instead of locating a home directory within the windows current user directory.

I created a folder called `home` within `C:\Hashicorp\Vagrant` and used that (`C:\Hashicorp\Vagrant\home`).

Setting windows environment variables is not hard (rather trivial actually) - you can find out how here: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

You'll have to do a restart to your system for it to take effect (it all worked after a reboot for me).

Comment: Works for me too. Thanks. But you don't have to restart the system, just open a new command prompt.

Answer (score 15):

I've found a slight variation to the @Reinsbrains answer. In order to have a home directory without spaces within its name. I created a junction to my user/home directory. In my case I decided to go with a Linux style structure, but any location would work. In an admin command prompt:

```
mkdir c:\home
mklink /j c:\home\maarten "c:\users\Maarten Bicknese"
```

Next set the `VAGRANT_HOME` environment variable to the newly created junction.

```
setx VAGRANT_HOME c:\home\maarten
```

Fire up a new command prompt and you're good to go!

Comment: Whups, you're absolutely right @WorkingMatt. According to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(v=ws.11).aspx the standard is to use a lowercase `j` as well. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I like this one better.