# Ruby directory error while installing vagrant on windows 7

Tags: ruby, windows, vagrant, virtualbox

I have installed the virtualbox and vagrant on windows 7 and I want to setup the vagrant instance for development but when installing the plugin I got this error. Here is the tutorial which I'm following. [edx-devstack](https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edX-Developer-Stack)

```
C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\devstack
λ vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
The directory where plugins are installed (the Vagrant home directory)
has a space in it. On Windows, there is a bug in Ruby when compiling
plugins into directories with spaces. Please move your Vagrant home
directory to a path without spaces and try again.
```

Path Variable

```
λ echo %PATH%
C:\Users\Muhammad Irfan\Downloads\Compressed\cmder\bin;C:\Users\Muhammad Irfan\Downloads\Compressed\cmder\vendor\msysgit\bin;C:\Users\Muhammad Irfan\Downloads\Compressed\cmder\vendor\msysgit\mingw\bin;C:\Users\Muhammad Irfan\Downloads\Compressed\cmder\vendor\msysgit\cmd;C:\Users\Muhammad Irfan\Downloads\Compressed\cmder\vendor\msysgit\share\vim\vim74;C:\Users\Muhammad Irfan\Downloads\Compressed\cmder;C:\Users\Muhammad Irfan\Downloads\Compressed\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu;C:\Users\Muhammad Irfan\Downloads\Compressed\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\
```

Ruby Version:

```
λ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your username contains space `C:\Users\Muhammad Irfan` as a result the paths are containing spaces. Which is not allowed as clearly mentioned in the error message. Fix that and issue can be resolved.

For reference: [Unable to install plugin hostmanager in vagrant in windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102156/unable-to-install-plugin-hostmanager-in-vagrant-in-windows-8-1)